# Extracting duplicity backup data

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, duplicity

I've made some backups of my previous systems using Deja Dup (duplicity). In my current distribution it's not available, so I've simply extracted the data. Now in order to make that data meaningful again I have to cat the files like that:

```
cat ? ?? > file
```

Question marks are dependable from number of files of course.

The structure of extracted data is like this:

```
some/long/path/to/file/[original_filename_converted_to_folder.extension]/
```

so the filename is a folder and within that folder there are numbered files (like 1, 2..20..300..etc). Different files (which now are folders) have different number of those numbered files inside them.

So I thought to get all directories where . is present. Then if there are no subdirectories in that directory cat all files to one, give that file folder name (because it's the actual file name), transfer it one directory upwards (..) and then delete that directory (the one used to create a file with filename)

So I started writing script, but I have some issues with it:

```
directories = "$(find . -type d)"
for i in "$directories"
do
  fdir = "$i"
  rdir = "$(dirname "$i")";
  fname = "$(basename "$i")";
  if [[ "$(basename "$i")" == *"."* ]] then
    cd "$i"
    FILECOUNT="$(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c)"
    DIRCOUNT="$(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c)"
    DIRCOUNT=$(( DIRCOUNT - 1 ))
    if DIRCOUNT == 0 then
      if FILECOUNT != 0 then
        # >> this is the problematic part
        DIGITS = "$(grep -o "[s|S]" <<<"$x" | wc -l)"
          cat "$QUESTIONMARKS" > "$fname"
          mv "$fname" "$rdir" +"/"+ "$fname"+".restored"
          rm *
          cd ..
          rmdir fname
          mv "$fname"+".restored" "$fname"
        # << end of problems
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

So the problem is - how do I generate question marks depending on file number in directory? if there is a 1 digit file number in directory then command should look like this:

```
cat ? > file
```

if there is 2 digit file number in directory, then:

```
cat ? ?? > file
```

if 3, then:

```
cat ? ?? ??? > file
```

You get the idea..

After this, I wrote a list of commands which should proceed, although - do I simply add them like this or do I have to wrap them to () ?

Is it ok to cd in such script? Will I not get into some issues?

Any other possible solutions to achieving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have directories that contains files called `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. (up to a variable limit) and you want to replace each directory by a file which has the same name as the directory, and is the concatenation of the files in numerical order.

In this answer, I'm going to use [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), because it's a lot easier to use than a combination of bash and other tools. You can translate the method to sh and find (bash and GNU find will be easier than plain sh and POSIX find).

First, to locate the directories, the presence of a dot doesn't seem like a very useful heuristics: you'll miss files whose name doesn't contain a dot and you'll hit directories whose name does contain a dot. Looking for directories that contain numerically-named files seems more reliable (though it isn't perfect, nothing is). Warning: untested code:

```
#!/bin/zsh
for dir in **/1(:h); do
  files=($dir/*(Nn:t))
  for ((i=1; i<=$#files; i++)); do
    # if the ith file isn't called i, skip this directory
    if [[ $files[i] != $i ]]; then files=; break; fi
  done
  if [[ -z $files ]]; then continue; fi
  # The directory contains only numbered files, and they're in sequence.
  # Concatenate the files, move the result into place and remove the directory.
  tmp=$(TMPDIR=$dir:h mktemp -d)
  mv -- $dir $tmp &&
  for x in $tmp/$dir:t/$^files; do cat -- $x; done >$tmp/file &&
  mv -- $tmp/file $dir &&
  rm -r $tmp
done
```

Explanation of zsh features:

- `:t` and `:h` are [history expansion modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) to take the directory part and the basename of a file respectively.
- `*(Nn)` uses [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `n` to sort file names in numerical order instead of lexicographic order, and `N` to get an empty array rather than an error if the directory is empty.
- The [`^` parameter expansion modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-RC_005fEXPAND_005fPARAM_002c-toggle) in `$dir/$^files` adds the prefix `$dir/` to each element of the array `files` (as opposed to adding it only to the first element).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I can't run this script. zsh is complaining about the opening clause on line 1:

`./zshscript.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ('
./zshscript.sh: line 1: for dir in **/1(:h); do'`

Comment: @EžiukasStebintisPasaulį Are you sure you ran the script with zsh? I just tested (not extensively, just with a sample input), and it is syntactically correct and seems to do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I've changed `tmp=$(TMPDIR=$dir:h mktemp -d)
  mv -- $dir $tmp &&
  cat -- $dir/$^files >$tmp/file &&
  mv -- $tmp/file $dir &&
  rm -r $tmp`
to `fname=$dir:t
cat -- $dir/$^files >$dir:h/$fname".restored" && 
rm -r $dir &&
mv -- $dir:h/$fname".restored" $dir:h/$fname` because I two problems with your code: 1. filename was not the original one (now I get one), 2. After running script instead of restored files there was temporary directory with root rights and inside there was a restored file with name 'file' and original directory from which contents the file was created.

Comment: But still thank you - this helped a lot. And I still have one problem, though - because the paths inside are quite long, when there is too much files, then I get `argument list too long: cat` any ideas how can I fix that? Most likely that is why I was trying to use question marks as arguments - at least such recommendation I found when there is a lot of files to cat. Any ideas?

Comment: @EžiukasStebintisPasaulį It's hard to follow what you did in a comment without the line breaks. Please edit my answer with your fix. Regarding “argument list too long”, wildcards wouldn't help (it's the length after wildcard expansion that matters). You can replace `cat -- $dir/$^files >$tmp/file` by `(cd -- $dir && cat $files) >$tmp/file` to make the problem unlikely (shorter command line), or by `for x in $dir/$^files; do cat -- $x; done >$tmp/file` to be sure.

Comment: So thanks! Modified your answer with my changes + your last comment about cat. Used the for version - just to be safe.

Comment: I see that my edit is not visible - why is that? Was my alteration of code bad?

Comment: @EžiukasStebintisPasaulį Your edit was rejected before I got to it, sorry. You shouldn't have left “EDIT” marks and the old code. You can see the outcome of your edit suggestions in [the “all actions” tab of your profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/61659?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). I fixed the bug in my code. I kept the temporary directory name, so that the restoration doesn't break if a directory has the same name that you chose in the restoration script.